# Showing a certain function is analytic given only continuity.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $z_0\in\Omega$.  Show that a function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic at $z_0$ iff

$$g(z) = \begin{cases} 
       \dfrac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0) & \text{if $z\neq z_0$}\\[6px]
       0 & \text{if $z=z_0$}
   \end{cases} $$
is continuous at $z_0$.

I think the forward direction is clear enough, but I am at a loss for a strategy for the reverse direction. I am new to the subject and would like to approach the problem from the ``ground level" if possible.

Comment: $g$ is continuous at $z_0$ if and only if $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0$, it need not be analytic at $z_0$. ($f$ is analytic at $z_0$ if it is representable by a power series on some neighbourhood of $z_0$.)

Comment: What do you mean by "analytic at $z_0\>$"? Maybe you have an $f$ in mind which is analytic in $\Omega\setminus\{z_0\}$ to start with.

Comment: Isn't $|z|^2$ a counter-example? It is complex differentiable at $0$, thus $g$ is continuous at 0, but it is not analytic.

Comment: Christian Blatter- Yes, I think "analytic at $z_0$" means as you say.

Comment: In my course we have not yet been introduced to the power series representation perspective yet.  It may be that we are abusing the the definition of analytic in this exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown above, $f$ need not be analytic at $z_0$, but the statement is true assuming $f$ is complex differenciable.

Assume first that $f$ is analytic at $z_0$. Then

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$$
exists, and the limit equals to $f'(z_0)$, so

$$\left( \lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}\right)-f'(z_0)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)\right)=0$$

Hence, $g$ is continous at $z_0$.

The other implication follows from the fact that since $g$ is continous at $z_0$, then

$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}-f'(z_0)\right)=0$$
So
$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z_0)$$

Therefore, $f$ is complex differentiable at $z_0.$